# Sending large data to the view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a situation where I have to send a large sum of data to the view which I am getting back from the model.

Something like this :

```
$modelData = array (
    array ( 
        array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
        array (
            array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
            array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
            array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
            .......
            array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
        )
    ),
    array ( 
        array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
        array (
            array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
            array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
            array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
            .......
            array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
        )
    ),
    .......
    .......,
    array ( 
        array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
        array (
            array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
            array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
            array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
            .......
            array ( 'mykey1' => 'somevalue1', 'mykey2' => 'somevalue2', ........ 'mykeyn' => 'somevaluen' ),
        )
    )
);

$data ['title'] = 'title';
$data ['x'] = 'something';
$data ['modelData'] = $modelData;


$this->load->view ( 'myview', $data );
```

As you can see it becomes too complex pretty soon.

Is there an another way to do it ?

Comment: Use JSON and parse it accordingly.

Comment: where is that array coming from?